# How can I use VBA to create an =AVERAGE formula in a dynamic cell with a dynamic range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a Sub that will allow me to replace a formula for every time the macro is run.

I'm able to select the range I want using:

```
Range("A3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("B5", ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1)).Select
```

And I'm able to find the cell in which I want the formula using:

```
Range("A3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1).Activate
```

Is there a way I can make a formula that says `=AVERAGE([selected range])`?

**Note: I do not want to just have the value in the cell. I need to have it so there is an active formula showing the results.**

Comment: See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4088852).  Once you have a `Range` containing the cells you want to average, you can just use something like `=AVERAGE(" & rng.Address & ")"`

Comment: Sounds like you could create a dynamic named range and refer to that.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem you are trying to do something like this:

```
Dim lrows As Long

lrows = Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row - 1

Range("A" & lrows + 1).Formula = "=AVERAGE(B5:B" & lrows & ")"
```

You should avoid using `SELECT`ing and `ACTIVATE`ing cells in your code, it slows it down and makes it less reliable.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the formula.  worksheetfunction.Average("Select range")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).